# How do you pull a branch from staging when you are in production using git?

Tags: git, github

So after switching and pulling the latest from production branch using:

```
git checkout production and then 
git pull origin production
```

I switched to branch feature/slides using

```
git checkout feature/slides
```

I know this is silly but How do I pull the latest from feature/slides located on the remote staging repository? I tried

```
git pull origin feature/slides
```

But that doesn't seem to update the code on in local environment or do anything.

Comment: What do you mean by "the latest from feature/slides located on the staging branch"? `git pull origin feature/slides` will fetch from the remote called `origin` and merge the changes to `feature/slides`, if there is anything new.

Comment: "How do I pull the latest from feature/slides located on the staging branch?" Since `feature/slides` is a branch, this does not make any sense. Do you mean the staging repo or remote?

Comment: "But that doesn't seem to update the code on in local environment or do anything." Please show the exact output.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice My mistake I meant the staging repo. I'll rephrase my question

Comment: @Samir Aguiar I would like to pull from the remote staging

Comment: `git pull staging...`

Comment: `origin` is the name of a remote. You can check which remote is that by running `git remote get-url origin`. If you want to pull from another repository, add it as a remote through `git remote add <name> <repo-url>` where `<name>` can be whatever you want. You can then pull from it with `git pull <name> <branch>`.

Comment: @SamirAguiar I used git pull origin staging feature/slides and this seemed to work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to configure `staging` as a remote in your local repository. You do this with the `git remote` command:

```
git remote add staging <remote URL>
```

Now you use this remote with `git pull` and `git push` commands just as you do `origin`:

```
git pull staging feature/slides
```

Comment: Would `git pull origin staging feature/slides` work as well?

Comment: @Mariton that only "works" if both `staging` and `feature/slides` are branches in the `origin` remote. Even then it does not do what you think. It fetches the two branches then does a three-way merge. Since the local repo is already up to date with `origin/feature/slides`, you can just do `git pull origin staging` to the same effect.

Comment: Yes you are correct `staging` and `feature/slides` are in the origin remote. So I tried `git pull staging feature/slides` and I got the following message  "Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists." So I figure that I need to do `git remote add staging <remote URL>` and then `git pull staging feature/slides`

Comment: @Mariton It seems like you have some difficulty with the terminology. Using the right words in the right way is important to avoid confusion. I suggest you do some research and reading to help you understand the difference between a remote, a repository, and a branch.

Comment: @Mariton Note that you can learn about each individual command with `git help <command>`.

Comment: I overlooked your last comment. Definitely makes sense. Yes, I'll do more reading on the subject. I understand your last comment but when I do a `git pull staging feature/slides` I get the message I mentioned in my previous message. `git remote add staging <remote URL>`

Comment: @Mariton you get that error message because `staging` is apparently a branch not a repository.